# Essa pergunta é "ampla demais"?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, razões-fechamento

Sou programador e <strike>ainda</strike> defensor do Flash, hoje em dia é difícil ver perguntas sobre ele e notei que [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/192390/ativar-flash-via-javascript) foi fechada como "ampla demais". A meu ver acho que a pergunta é bem específica: ele quer ativar o Flash Player no navegador via javascript. Tanto que a <strike>única</strike> resposta também foi bem específica: "não" é possível, "mas" você pode fazer o procedimento "dessa" maneira. Até tentei editar a pergunta pra deixa-la melhor mas ela já consta como fechada.

Gostaria de saber porque ela é ampla demais e foi tão negativada?

Comment: Cara, fechamento não é nada absoluto. Se acha que a pergunta deve ser reaberta, é só votar pra reabrir (não sei se esta opção já aparece pra você).

Comment: Votei para reabrir, eu também sou um dos poucos que eventualmente usa AS3.0, não necessariamente o Flash, achei a pergunta bem ruinzinha, mas não tem aonde melhor e gerou uma boa resposta para futuros visitantes, ou seja no geral parece ter trazido bons resultados.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, uso o Flash Develop para programação mas como trabalho com DS alguns dos nossos plugins precisam de um bom "tapa" no visual e pra isso o Flash é melhor, rsrs.

Comment: @jbueno, não aparece essa opção pra mim, infelizmente. Acho que ela deve ser reaberta e fiz essa pergunta aqui no meta justamente porque "fechamento não é nada absoluto" ;)